# UI elements not showing up when simulator is run

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, uiviewcontroller

I am having a problem with some of my UI elements not being displayed. I have a start screen with two buttons, both have to same transitions. When I click on the one on the right, all the stuff I have on the viewcontroller in storyboard is displayed, a button and a switch with an image above. When I click on the button on the left, only the image is displayed. The other elements "pop-up" when the screen is tapped.

Is this code related or just and xcode bug? How to do I fix this?

Here is a Gif of what was described above
http://gph.is/2aomHtk

Comment: It seems a layout problem with tab bar

Comment: what is the top constraint ?

Comment: @BhadreshMulsaniya what do you mean by that? Are you talking about a constraint on the image?

Comment: @WeiJay would giving the tab bar a custom class fix this?

Comment: @JoeMacksood I am talking about top constraint for imageview's superview.

Comment: Is it Scrollview ?

Comment: @BhadreshMulsaniya yes it was, the navigation bar was making unnecessary space which off set it, thank you!

Comment: @JoeMacksood Welcome buddy :-)